# WCF service + passing and receiving same object to/from service & client

Tags: c#, wcf

Please I need best practices for WCF in my case below,

I need to send the object instance to WCF service, WCF service processes and updates the same object and sends back to client.

So with best practice should i need to maintain 2 object instances? or I can use same instance and update and send back. Please advise.

see below code for how I am writing currently. please help.

```
[OperationContract]   
 Customer DoProcess(Customer customer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't want to persist the sent object then there is no need to maintain two objects. It is always advisable to not to even create multiple references, nor objects.

In case of Objects you will have a separate copy, that means more memory, and in reference variable also you will waste 4 to 8 bytes + CPU overhead.

With the principle of memory management, I recommend you update the same and return back.

Comment: Only thing I would like to know if i use the Customer instance at client after service call I will get the updated Customer instance?? I tried it and it does not works :-(

Comment: You need to return it back ; WCF is a message based system - you pass around serialized (text/xml) messages. There's no "object references" that you can pass around. Thus you method should return back ... in other words  your client code will be: customer = webservice.DoSomething(customer);

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following scenario:
client calls the WCF servcice function and passes a customer as parameter.

```
Customer c = new Customer();
WCFProxy.DoProcess(c);
```

Now the object will be serialized and sent to the wcf service.
the service will now execute the DoProcess function as follows;

```
Customer DoProcess(Customer customer){
customer.name = 'abc';
return customer;
}
```

this will not update the customer passed by the client. It will return a new customer that will be serialized and passed to the client.

So, on the client you may set your customer instance to the returned customer as such:

```
c = WCFProxy.DoProcess(c);
```